# Copying data from one Pointer to another, but the complete data is not getting copied in c

Tags: c, pointers, memcpy

```
**typedef struct RxData{
    int *dataptr;
}Dataat;
int RxAuthData[1][3];**

**void main()
{
    int *dest, i=0;
    int arr[3]={10,11,12};
    int *src = &arr[0];
    Dataat DataCapture[1] = {
    RxAuthData[0]
    };
    dest = DataCapture[0].dataptr;
    memcpy(dest,src,3);
    i=0;
    while(i<3)
    {
        printf("%d\n",DataCapture[0].dataptr[i]);
        i++;
    }
}**
```

dest pointer is holding only 10, remaining two values its not holding.
What is the mistake that i am doing here.
I need the two 2D array to capture the data.

Comment: `memcpy(dest,src,3);` should be something like `memcpy(dest,src,3*sizeof(int));`

Comment: thank you! it worked..